# WebApi v2 ExceptionHandler not working with HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exceptionhandler

How comes that a custom ExceptionHandler is never called and instead a standard response When Call HTTP Methods Post

This my code

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        //Handler Custom Exception
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new CustomExceptionHandler());

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new JsonOutputDateTime());
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Remove the XML formatter (Json Only)
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

ExceptionHandler.cs

```
 public class CustomExceptionHandler : System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler
{
    public override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        SystemExceptionReturn returnObj = new SystemExceptionReturn();
        returnObj.responseCode = "xxxx";
        returnObj.responseMessage = "System Error";     
        var response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObj);
        context.Result = new ResponseMessageResult(response);

        return base.HandleAsync(context, cancellationToken);
    }

    public virtual bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
    private class TextPlainErrorResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response =
                             new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            response.Content = new StringContent(Content);
            response.RequestMessage = Request;
            return Task.FromResult(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax.xs

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

    }

}
```

my Controller

```
public class gController : ApiController
{       
    [HttpPost]
    public bool haha(int id)
    {
        bool res = false;
        try
        {
            int ans = id / 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return res;
    }       
}
```

This response when I call localhost:xxxx/api/v1/g/haha

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Attempted to divide by zero.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.DivideByZeroException"}
```

but when i change HttpPost to HttpGet it' working for me.

Please someone help me

Sorry for my English

**UPDATE**

I found when test in localhost is't not working but when Deploy to IIS it' working 
Thank you so much for help

Comment: Can you share the response that you get when you change POST to GET?

Comment: GET response {"responseCode":"xxxx","responseMessage":"System Error"}

Answer (score -1):

To Send POST request to `localhost:xxxx/api/v1/g/haha` URL
if you change Id parameter to be received [FromBody] it will work.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public bool haha([FromBody]int id)
        {
            bool res = false;
            try
            {
                int ans = id / 0;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: are you adding id parameter in the body while sending post request?

Comment: This is not because of the `[FromBody]` attribute, this is more of known CORS issue, though I agree OP has not provided the complete link with query parameter thus leading to confusion